# Alter entity reference autocomplete field

Tags: views, 7, entities

I have made a module to alter the way entity reference works with autcomplete fields. I have override the entity_reference_autcomplete function where i have changed the following line:

```
        $key = "$label ($entity_id)";
```

with

```
        $key = "$label";
```

It seems to work when completing fields in form , but after the form has been submitted the autcomomplete field gets blank and the result is not saved . How can i solve this issue ?

Comment: You will also need to use a modified submit function. probably the default one tries to get $entity_id from the input using some regex or something

Comment: @AyeshK can you give more details ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be done by writing a custom CTools EntityReference selection plugin.  Your new class would just extend EntityReference_SelectionHandler_Generic_node and I think it would only need to override the getLabel() method to make things "just work".